# PinFieldAutoFill background color does not change

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, sms-verification

I'm using the [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) package to create an SMS verification page. I use the [PinFieldAutoFill](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_input_text_field/example) widget to insert the sms code.

I want the background color of the widget to be white instead of grey:

[image]

How do I change it?

Here is my code:

```
PinFieldAutoFill(
      autoFocus: autoFocus,
      codeLength: smsCode.length,
      currentCode: autoComplete ? smsCode : null,
      decoration: BoxLooseDecoration(
        strokeColorBuilder: PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.black26),
        bgColorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Colors.white),
        strokeWidth: 1.2,
      ),
      onCodeChanged: (p0) {
        if (p0?.length == smsCode.length && !autoComplete) {
          context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginEventSubmitSmsCode(p0!));
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: try to change `transparent` to `white`

Comment: I updated my question, it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you defined a global theme for the inputDecorationTheme

You probably have this theme in your global theme

```
inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
        fillColor: Color(0xfff5f5f5),
        filled: true,
)
```

To override it, you can use the theme widget to wrap your PinFieldAutoFill

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          filled: false,
        ),
      ),
      child: PinFieldAutoFill(...
```